# React failed to set value for Radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I want to set a value for Radio button, however after I check one of them, then it's not checked after I set the state for a property of an object.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.completeChange = this.completeChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            hero: {}
        };
    }

    getHero() {

    }

    completeChange(event) {
        var hero = { ...this.state.hero
        };
        hero.Complete = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            hero: hero
        }, () => {
            //when the callback is called, the radio button is not checked
            console.log(this.state.hero.Complete);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <div className="complete">
                  <label>Choose one: </label>
                  <input type="radio" id="Complete" value="true" onChange={this.completeChange}
                      value='true' checked={this.state.hero.Complete == true} />Yes
                      <input type="radio" id="Complete" value="false" onChange={this.completeChange}
                      value='false' checked={this.state.hero.Complete == false} />No
             </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

What is wrong here? Can anyone here solve my problem?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: try this completeChange(event) {
    const { hero } = this.state;
    const nextHero = {
      ...hero,
      Complete: !hero.Complete
    }
    this.setState({ hero: nextHero }, () => {
      //when the callback is called, the radio button is not checked
      console.log(this.state.hero.Complete);
    });
  }

Comment: @Orgil can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state.
Try it this way:

```
completeChange(event) {
    const {hero} = this.state;
    const nextHero = {
      ...hero,
      Complete: true
    }
    this.setState({ hero: nextHero }, () => {
        //when the callback is called, the radio button is not checked
        console.log(this.state.hero.Complete);
    });
}
```

If you want to **toggle** the state then i suggest using the [function version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), because state updates are async and when ever your next state relies on previous state you should use the function argument of `setState` to ensure you get the most recent state.

Something like this:

```
  completeChange(event) {
    this.setState(state => {
      const { hero } = state;
      const nextHero = {
        ...hero,
        Complete: !hero.Complete
      };
      return {
        hero: nextHero
      };
    });
  }
```

And if you want to set the state based on the value of the button that was clicked you can check `event.target.value`:

```
completeChange(event) {
    const { hero } = this.state;
    const isComplete = event.target.value === 'true';
    const nextHero = {
      ...hero,
      Complete: isComplete
    };
    this.setState({hero: nextHero});
  }
```

Here is a running example of your code:

```js
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.completeChange = this.completeChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      hero: {}
    };
  }

  getHero() {}

  completeChange(event) {
    const { hero } = this.state;
    const isComplete = event.target.value === 'true';
    const nextHero = {
      ...hero,
      Complete: isComplete
    };
    this.setState({hero: nextHero});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="complete">
        <label>Choose one: </label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="Complete"
          value="true"
          onChange={this.completeChange}
          checked={this.state.hero.Complete == true}
        />Yes
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="Complete"
          value="false"
          onChange={this.completeChange}
          checked={this.state.hero.Complete == false}
        />No
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**By the way**
Never do `==` against a Boolean:

```
this.state.hero.Complete == true
```

Its better to use the `===` instead in this case:

```
this.state.hero.Complete === true
```

I wrote a [post](https://medium.com/@sagiv.bengiat/javascript-vs-the-truth-45992607c27) about that if you're interested in more details.

Comment: But in the UI, the radio button is checked then immediately unchecked. Can you solve the problem?

Comment: i added a running example, i don't see what you described. but there is a different problem and your logic is not respecting on which button was clicked, but that can be solved as well, maybe checking the name (to group the buttons) or value via `event.target`

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you explain what do you change in completeChange function?

Comment: Two things, 1) not mutating the state. 2) checking the actual value of `event.target.event === 'true'` to decide on which button was clicked.

Comment: Why I write "const isComplete = event.target.value" instead of "const isComplete = event.target.value === 'true'" as you said, I check my radio button and it's undo immediately?

Comment: `event.target.value` is a `String` not a `Boolean`

Comment: don't use `==` against a `Boolean`. i've added a link in the answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could directly check your `e.target.value=='true'` and set into your state like this.

You can check here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-failed-to-set-value-for-radio-button) demo.

**Code Snippet**

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.completeChange = this.completeChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      hero: {}
    };
  }

  getHero() {

  }

  completeChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      hero: event.target.value == 'true'
    }, () => {
      //when the callback is called, the radio button is not checked
      console.log(this.state.hero);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="complete">
        <label>Choose one: </label>
        <input type="radio" onChange={this.completeChange}
          value={true} checked={this.state.hero} />Yes

        <input type="radio" value={false} onChange={this.completeChange} checked={!this.state.hero} />No
             </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```